# Stack pointer maximum values stored -SRAM memory

Tags: pointers, memory, stack, atmega16

I would like to know if it is possible to know the maximal values stored in the stack pointer with that: (see the code below form my .lss file)
And in the worst case, I would like to know what are these informations store in the SP?
It is possible to know the SRAM adress ?

Thanks by advance

Alex

PS: I use a ATmega16

```
__________________________

.dseg memory usage only counts static data declared with .byte

ATmega16 register use summary:
r0 :  10 r1 :   0 r2 :   0 r3 :   0 r4 :   0 r5 :   0 r6 :   0 r7 :   0 
r8 :   0 r9 :   0 r10:   0 r11:   0 r12:   0 r13:   0 r14:   0 r15:   7 
r16:  66 r17:  10 r18:   2 r19:   0 r20:   0 r21:   0 r22:   0 r23:   0 
r24:   0 r25:  15 r26:   0 r27:   0 r28:   0 r29:   0 r30:   8 r31:   8 
x  :   0 y  :   0 z  :   0 
Registers used: 8 out of 35 (22.9%)

ATmega16 instruction use summary:
.lds  :   0 .sts  :   0 adc   :   0 add   :   1 adiw  :   1 and   :   0 
andi  :   0 asr   :   0 bclr  :   0 bld   :   0 brbc  :   0 brbs  :   0 
brcc  :   1 brcs  :   0 break :   0 breq  :   2 brge  :   0 brhc  :   0 
brhs  :   0 brid  :   0 brie  :   0 brlo  :   1 brlt  :   0 brmi  :   0 
brne  :   7 brpl  :   0 brsh  :   4 brtc  :   0 brts  :   0 brvc  :   0 
brvs  :   0 bset  :   0 bst   :   0 call  :   0 cbi   :   0 cbr   :   0 
clc   :   1 clh   :   0 cli   :   0 cln   :   0 clr   :   3 cls   :   0 
clt   :   0 clv   :   0 clz   :   0 com   :   0 cp    :   0 cpc   :   0 
cpi   :  11 cpse  :   0 dec   :   1 eor   :   0 fmul  :   0 fmuls :   0 
fmulsu:   0 icall :   0 ijmp  :   0 in    :   2 inc   :   0 jmp   :  13 
ld    :   0 ldd   :   0 ldi   :  38 lds   :   7 lpm   :   3 lsl   :   0 
lsr   :   0 mov   :   6 movw  :   0 mul   :   0 muls  :   0 mulsu :   0 
neg   :   0 nop   :   0 or    :   0 ori   :   0 out   :  14 pop   :   2 
push  :   2 rcall :  22 ret   :   6 reti  :   1 rjmp  :   6 rol   :   2 
ror   :   0 sbc   :   0 sbci  :   0 sbi   :   0 sbic  :   0 sbis  :   1 
sbiw  :   0 sbr   :   0 sbrc  :   0 sbrs  :   0 sec   :   1 seh   :   0 
sei   :   1 sen   :   0 ser   :   0 ses   :   0 set   :   0 sev   :   0 
sez   :   0 sleep :   0 spm   :   0 st    :   0 std   :   0 sts   :  11 
sub   :   2 subi  :  11 swap  :   0 tst   :   2 wdr   :   0 
Instructions used: 32 out of 113 (28.3%)

ATmega16 memory use summary [bytes]:
Segment   Begin    End      Code   Data   Used    Size   Use%
---------------------------------------------------------------
[.cseg] 0x000000 0x000236    430    136    566   16384   3.5%
[.dseg] 0x000060 0x000066      0      6      6    1024   0.6%
[.eseg] 0x000000 0x000000      0      0      0     512   0.0%
```